# why min-height is not working?

Tags: html, css

hi part of my html code is something like this

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

In CSS i have

```
#content
{

    min-height:600px;
}
```

But i am expecting this div with id=content to extend height which is not happening. How to fix this?

for a complete code you can check at this jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/eYMz3/

Comment: `container` <-- Invalid tag and the code you've shared works for me http://jsfiddle.net/eYMz3/1/

Comment: Woa, that's a lot of code in your fiddle! The code from your question [works as specced](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z54J/). Please try to narrow down the problem and include a [minimal repro](http://sscce.org) *in the question*.

Comment: Do you want the "Photo Stories" `div` to be inside the grey background?

Comment: @NickR exactly. that is what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `overflow:hidden` on the `#content`

http://jsfiddle.net/eYMz3/3/

The problem was that the elements you want to stretch `#content` were uncleared floats. These don't stretch their parent.

If you use anything other than `overflow: visible` (default behavior), it will use block formatting context which will basically clear the floats.

[w3 Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)

You could also have added `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` just before the end of your `#content` div to clear your floats.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. which is the better practice? overflow:hidden or clear:both??

Comment: @KrishGowda, it's really up to you. I generally prefer the first as it doesn't add to the dom.

Comment: I would go for the semantically correct option. Are you trying to hide overflow or clear the floats? You are trying to clear the floats so I'd use that if I were otherwise unsure. I would imagine it is personal preference though. I just initially thought that this solution would be hiding the content at a glance and thought that sounded crazy til I read the explanation in more detail.

Comment: Either way is fine. I suppose if you have other people looking at your code you might want to add a comment on the `overflow:hidden`. Otherwise there is nothing wrong with a `clear:both` div at the bottom and that is pretty common practice as well.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

That should do it, as "container" on it's own isn't valid

Comment: Unless explicitly defined with Javascript, custom tag names don't get rendered.

Comment: Thank you. i updated the code. but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here, is that you're using `float`s, but never clearing them, meaning the parent element doesn't know the height to extend to.

To fix this:

You can use the micro clearfix hack from http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

```
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Then add the class to `<div id="content">`, so it becomes `<div id="content" class="cf">`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eYMz3/2/)**

You can read up on floats here - under the section "*The great collapse*" - http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that all of the elements inside #content have also float: left applied. The result of this is that the element itself will not respond to the heights of elements inside it. In this instance, min-height and height will do the same thing, and the height of #content will not extend.

Other than that, everything seems to be working as one would expect in the document you provided. I might've misunderstood your question, but I am unable to add a comment asking for clarification because it tells me I don't have enough points.